# Download an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I just want to be able to press on a button and get an xmldocument file to download.

I've tried allot of things, for example:

```
XmlDocument doc As XmlDocument() = //Method that gets a xmldocument
Response.Clear()
this.Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
xmldoc.Save(this.Response.OutputStream)
```

and

```
Dim xmldocument As XmlDocument = //Method that gets a xmldocument
Using stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim xmlWriter As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
            xmldocument.WriteTo(xmlWriter)
            xmlWriter.Flush()

            Dim byteArray As Byte() = stream.ToArray()
            Response.Clear()
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=MyExportedFile.xml")
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString())
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray)
            xmlWriter.Close()
        End Using
```

Nothing works, am i forgetting something obvious? because nothing works, the xmldocument is loaded everything seems fine but the file never downloads and the "response" does absolutely nothing!

An answer in Csharp or VB.NET would be helpfull

Comment: The code samples are very confusing, and don't look like they're even compilable. It would help if you posted the actual code.

Comment: In the code you posted you don't load any content into the Response.

Comment: it has no relation with xml. just open it as txt file, write it into response.

Comment: @breischl It is the actual code, copy paste it into an aspx and it'll run perfectly just replace the 'method that gets a xmldocument with an xml document that is filled.
the reason it looks weird is because this site made it all red for some reason.

Comment: No, that code won't work if you copy and paste it. You were missing semi colons, you're mixing up variable names, and in the first example it looks like your mixing C# and VB code.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you are trying to achieve.  You're tagging the question as asp.net so you could be either trying to download an xml file from another location, or you may (conceivably) mean that you want to start sending the bytes of an xml file from the server to the client.  Is it one of these two, or something else entirely?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that you were trying to download an XmlDocument from somewhere else, rather than trying to send an XmlDocument to a client. I get it now. So, what do you mean by "the file never downloads"?

Comment: Dim xmldocument As XmlDocument = method that gets it
So i'm trying to make it so that that document gets downloaded without it having to be saved serverside.
And yeah i pasted it from previous examples i tried. i work in VB.NET no semicolons needed

Comment: want it to download on the client

Comment: you are trying to send xml document to the client , not down load it from external location. can you trim down the code so its clear to read?. for starters why don't you write to the response object directly why do you need memorystream , and the flush() should be called on the response stream.

Comment: because i was desprate and i tried the obvious. the first example should be clear to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"
<root name='rootAttribute'>
    <OrderRequest name='one' />
    <OrderRequest name='two' />
    <OrderRequest name='three' />
</root>
"); // Load some random xml - use function to load whatever you need

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
{
    doc.WriteTo(writer); // Write to memorystream
}

byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:",
                    "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("samplefile.xml")); // Replace with name here
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
ms.Flush(); // Probably not needed
ms.Close();
```

Comment: It's still not downloading..
Going to check with a colleague that has more experience with this application maybe there's something i'm missing.

Comment: The above code is definitely working in the sample site I have configured.  Ensure that there is no other output prior to this function.

Comment: Figured out the problem, your sample does works I didn't perform the download function at the page_load and i wanted to perform this action with a button which didn't work so i used iframe to call another page that doesn't pop up or become visible in any way and put the code in the page_load of that page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Write(MethodThatReturnsXMLDoc().innerXml)
```